# What does Admiral Kirk whisper to Doctor McCoy?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ii-the-wrath-of-khan

About 30 minutes into *Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan* (1982), Kirk is performing an inspection of the training crew on board the Enterprise. Kirk inspects engineering and then says to McCoy "I'll be on the bridge" and goes up the elevator.

McCoy responds "What about the rest of the inspection?"

Kirk whispers something and waves his hand making a "no" gesture.

I've seen this film so many times over the years and have never been able to figure out what he whispers. It looks like he might be saying "I loathe…" but while replaying the scene it doesn't seem to match.

Does anyone know what is said?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[According to the script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/startrek2_wrathofkhan.txt), he is saying "Later".

> **BONES:** (dry) *Admiral!  What about the rest of the inspection?*
>
> **KIRK:** (mouths word) **Later.**

Comment: Definitely saying later. Can see it in his lips.

Answer (score 2):

There's a little more context provided in the film's [*official novelisation*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Wrath_of_Khan).

Kirk is telling Bones that he'll finish it *"later"*, which seems to be what he mouths in the film.

> "What about the rest of your inspection … Admiral?" McCoy said. He let
> the tone of his voice creep over into not completely benign mockery.
> Needling Jim Kirk was one of the few ways to get him to take a good
> hard look at himself.
>
> Getting him drunk certainly had not worked.
>
> **"I'll finish it later, Doctor," Jim said mildly. "After we're under
> way."**